# Angular2: Adding components dynamically

Tags: angular

I am planning to add dynamic components at certain location in my Angular 2 app. I tried adding anchor points but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an anchor Point  in html

In ts file

```
constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}
```

Create a component factory
Get the reference of the anchor point
Bind any data if required
Run detect changes for updating it

Answer (score 0):

```
dateComparator(filterLocalDateAtMidnight, cellValue) {
  // Convert the string date cellValue to a Date object:
  var dateAsString = cellValue;
  if (dateAsString == null) return -1;

  var dateParts = dateAsString.split('T')[0].split('-');
  var timeParts = dateAsString.split('T')[1]?.split(':') || ["00", "00", "00"];
  var cellDate = new Date(Number(dateParts[0]), Number(dateParts[1]) - 1, Number(dateParts[2]), Number(timeParts[0]), Number(timeParts[1]), Number(timeParts[2]));

  var filterLocalDateAtEOD = new Date(filterLocalDateAtMidnight.getFullYear(), filterLocalDateAtMidnight.getMonth(), filterLocalDateAtMidnight.getDate(), 23, 59, 59);

  if (cellDate.getTime() <= filterLocalDateAtEOD.getTime() && cellDate.getTime() >= filterLocalDateAtMidnight.getTime()) {
    return 0;
  } else if (cellDate.getTime() < filterLocalDateAtMidnight.getTime()) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```